# In ios14, text field borderstyle does not work properly

Tags: ios, uitextfield, background-image, ios14

I have simply added a background image to textField in the storyboard and it was working fine before iOS 14, now in iOS 14, the background image to textField is not showing up. has anyone found the solution to this instead of using UIImageView in the text field background?
I have set border style to none (screenshot shown below), still not working on iOS-14.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A [similar question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658890) was asked in apple's forums.

looks like you have to change the border style to anything different than round, you can set it in IB just below background image dropdown menu.